# Updating Label text after OptionMenu selection changes

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

My objective is to update the contents of the label `price`, every time that a new item in option menu `w` is selected. This is my code so far, but it is returning errors that I am not sure how to fix.

```
class App(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)

        Label(master, text="Ore:").grid(row=0)
        Label(master, text="Price:").grid(row=1)
        self.price = Label(master, text="0.00").grid(row=1, column=1)

        variable = StringVar(master)
        variable.set("Select an ore") # default value

        def displayPrice(self):
            self.price = orePrice[self.w.get()]

        self.w = OptionMenu(master, variable, *orePrice, command=displayPrice).grid(row=0, column=1)

        # here is the application variable
        self.contents = StringVar()
        # set it to some value
        self.contents.set("this is a variable")
        # tell the entry widget to watch this variable
        #self.w.bind('<Button-1>', )
```

You can assume that:

```
orePrice = {'Gold': 300, 'Silver': 50, 'Bronze': 10} # etc... you can add more if you feel like it.
```

I'm a newbie at Python GUI, hence the messy and/or badly written code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ammended your code. Now whenever you change ore type, the price field is updated:

```
from tkinter import *


class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)

        Label(master, text="Ore:").grid(row=0)
        Label(master, text="Price:").grid(row=1)

        self.priceVar = StringVar()
        self.priceVar.set("0.00")

        self.price = Label(master, textvariable=self.priceVar).grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.orePrice = {'Gold': 300, 'Silver': 50, 'Bronze': 10}

        variable = StringVar(master)
        variable.set("Select an ore") # default value


        self.w = OptionMenu(master, variable, *self.orePrice, command=self.displayPrice).grid(row=0, column=1)

        # here is the application variable
        self.contents = StringVar()
        # set it to some value
        self.contents.set("this is a variable")
        # tell the entry widget to watch this variable
        #self.w.bind('<Button-1>', )

    def displayPrice(self, value):
          self.priceVar.set(self.orePrice[value])


root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```