# Changing state of tkinter entry box depending on value of OptionMenu

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using python 2.7 and trying to change the state of a tkinter entry box depending on the value of an OptionMenu widget. I found an example of how to do it online [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24391688/updating-label-text-after-optionmenu-selection-changes), it's for python 3 but I don't think that's the issue (correct me if I am wrong). Some example code is below,

```
from Tkinter import *

class App:

    def _disable_f2(self):
        if self.filt.get() == 'bandpass':
            self.filter_menu.configure(state='normal')
        else:
            self.filter_menu.configure(state='disabled')



    def __init__(self, master):



        self.f2var = Tkinter.StringVar()
        self.f2var.set('5.0')
        self.f2_entry = Tkinter.Entry(master, textvariable=self.f2var,
                                      width=5)

        self.f2_entry.pack()

        self.filt = Tkinter.StringVar()
        self.filt.set('bandpass')

        self.filter_menu = Tkinter.OptionMenu(master, self.filt, 
                                              'bandpass', 'lowpass ', 
                                              'highpass', 
                                              command=self._disable_f2)        

        self.filter_menu.pack(ipadx=50)

root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

however, I keep getting the following error even though I am not passing two arguments. Anyone know what the cause is?

```
TypeError: _disable_f2() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If _disable_f2 is being given two arguments, let it have what it wants.. try below...
:)

```
from Tkinter import *

class App:

    def _disable_f2(self, master):
        if self.filt.get() == 'bandpass':
            self.filter_menu.configure(state='normal')
        else:
            self.filter_menu.configure(state='disabled')



    def __init__(self, master):



        self.f2var = StringVar()
        self.f2var.set('5.0')
        self.f2_entry = Entry(master, textvariable=self.f2var,
                                      width=5)

        self.f2_entry.pack()

        self.filt = StringVar()
        self.filt.set('bandpass')

        self.filter_menu = OptionMenu(master, self.filt, 
                                              'bandpass', 'lowpass ', 
                                              'highpass', 
                                              command=self._disable_f2)        

        self.filter_menu.pack(ipadx=50)

root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just accept one more argument and print it, you can find out what the argument is that is passed by the `OptionMenu`:

```
def _disable_f2(self, arg):
    print arg
```

You will see it prints the new value of the `OptionMenu`. Because this argument is passed you need the function to accept it, and you actually are using it (with `self.filt.get()`) so it's fine that it's passed.

You can rewrite your `_disable_f2` function to:

```
def _disable_f2(self, option):
    if option == 'bandpass':
        self.f2_entry.configure(state='normal')
    else:
        self.f2_entry.configure(state='disabled')
```

In your original code you disabled the optionmenu when the option was not `'bandpass'`, but I assume you want to disable the entry right? That's what this code does.

Also, if you use `from Tkinter import *`, you don't have to use `Tkinter.StringVar()`, but you can just use `StringVar()`. Same goes for `Entry(...)`, `OptionMenu(...)` and `Tk()`.
Allthough I would advise to use `import Tkinter as tk`, and use `tk.StringVar()` etc.