# Tkinter update label on optionmenu dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python, user-interface, dictionary, tkinter

Here we use a GUI to select a handset and auto update a handset_cost.
The problem is how to update a tkinter textvariable in a dictionary of widgets.

I'd like to extend this simpler solution: [Updating Label text after OptionMenu selection changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24391688/updating-label-text-after-optionmenu-selection-changes)

You'll see from running the code below, only the final row is (incorrectly) updated when you select a handset. I've tried everything I can think of but I'm too inexperienced to see how to get the function 'displayPrice' to reference a value for each row. Please can you help, thanks.

```
import tkinter as tk
import datetime


class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, background="black")
        root.title("Mobile Order Quote")

        table = tk.Frame(self, background="black")
        table.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        data = [(1, ),(2, ),(3, ),(5, )]

        handset_dict1 = {'apple_iphone': 500.0, 'two_cans_plus_string': 50.0, 'samsung_galaxy': 800.0, 'none': 0.0}                     

        table = tk.Frame(self, background="black")
        table.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.widgets = {}

            # MAKE 'big_tuple': solving the list of tuples problem - make a tuple of tuples and format too
        x = list(data)
        list_of_lists = [list(elem) for elem in x]

        big_list = []
        for i in list_of_lists:
            data1=(str(i[0]))
            big_list.append(data1)

        big_tuple = tuple(big_list)
        #global big_tuple

        row = 0
        for rent_id in (big_tuple):

            HLabel0 = tk.Label(table, text = "ID", fg = "white", background="black")
            HLabel9 = tk.Label(table, text = "Proposed_Handset", fg = "white", background="black")
            HLabel10 = tk.Label(table, text = "Handset_Cost", fg = "white", background="black")

            HLabel0.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx=1, pady=1) 
            HLabel9.grid(row = 0, column = 9, padx=1, pady=1)
            HLabel10.grid(row = 0, column = 10, padx=1, pady=1)

            row += 1
            handset = tk.StringVar(root) # creates tkvar for the handsets
            handset.set('none')

            handsetCost = tk.DoubleVar(root)
            handsetCost.set(0)

            def displayPrice(value):
                handsetCost.set(handset_dict1[value])


            self.widgets[rent_id] = {
                "rent_id": tk.Label(table, text=rent_id),
                "handset": tk.OptionMenu(table, handset, *handset_dict1.keys(), command=displayPrice, ), 
                "handset_cost": tk.Label(table, textvariable =handsetCost), }

            self.widgets[rent_id]["rent_id"].grid(row=row, column=0, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)
            self.widgets[rent_id]["handset"].grid(row=row, column=9, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)
            self.widgets[rent_id]["handset_cost"].grid(row=row, column=10, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is a very long piece of code you're provided. Is there any way you could reduce it down to just the critical part affecting your results?

Comment: @asongtoruin - thank you, I agree. I've already shortened it and removed all the buttons and functionality. I'll have a further look.

Comment: This code needs to be reduced. For example, do you really need 13 label widgets? Why can't you use just one or two for this question? Does the specific font or page title really matter? You can remove over 40 lines just by cutting the number of labels down.

Comment: @BryanOakley - thank you. Another rookie lesson learnt. Hopefully, now, this is acceptable code to ask for people's help.

Comment: @asongtoruin - sorry, I wasted your time before with my bloated code. Could I politely rekindle your interest in this question?

Comment: Just taking a quick look I think your problem lies on `handsetCost`. There is nothing set up to differentiate each `handsetCost` from the last. I will have to dig a little deeper tonight when I get home if no one else has solved this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The working solution changed considerably from the original code.

I've posted a solution in case it helps someone.

The handset and handset_cost variables were initially separated because we didn't want the string and float components together in one variable.
However, the solution was to simply combine them as a single field:

```
HLabel9= tk.Label(table, text = "Proposed_Handset_&_cost")


"handset": ttk.Combobox(table, textvariable=handset, 
               values[*handset_dict1], ),
```

We then extracted the values, for example:

```
hs_buy_list = []


for rent_id in (sorted(self.widgets.keys())):
        hs_buy_price =  self.widgets[rent_id]['handset'] # handset and buy
        new_hs_buy = hs_buy_price.get()
        hs_buy_list.append(new_hs_buy)

buy_hs_int = [] # splits out the buy price of handsets 
        for i in hs_buy_list:
            buy_hs_int.append(i.split(':')[1].rstrip('}'))
```